# How to create numpy arrays automatically?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to create arrays by for loop to assign automatically array names.

But using a for loop, it didn't work and creating a dictionary with numpy.array() in it, does not work, too. Currently, I have no more ideas...
I am not really safe in handling with python.

```
   import numpy as np

   for file_name in folder:
       file_name = np.array()
       file_name.extend((blabla, blabla1))
```

I expected to get arrays with automatically assigned names, like `file_name1`, `file_name2`, ...
But I got the advice, "redeclared `file_name` defined above without usage" and the output was at line `file_name = np.array()`

> TypeError: array() missing required argument 'object' (pos 1) ...

Comment: You should be using a dictionary or list. That’s what they’re there for. Using a dictionary, your `file_name` variable would be the keys in the dict.

Comment: The `redeclared` message is from your IDE (pycharm?), which warns about bad programming style.  You are assigning an object to the variable `file_name`, but not doing anything with it.  The `typeError` comes from Python interpreter, saying that you are not using the `np.array` function right.

Comment: WHy do you want a bunch of variables with names that look like file names?  When you already have the names in a list (`folder`)?  A file name like `c:/path/name.txt` is not a valid variable name in Python.

Comment: @hpaulj: about your first comment, yes, I didn't know how to handle with .. about your second comment, I wanted the file name not the path to be a variable name

Comment: @MarkMeyer: yes, thank you

Comment: What's the file name if it isn't the path?  or some part of the path?  How are you going to reference those arrays later?  With the same globals trick?  That will get old pretty quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `globals()` if you really want to use the strings as named variables.

```
globals()[filename] = np.array()
```

Example:

```
>>> globals()['test'] = 1
>>> test
1
```

Of course this populates the global namespace. Otherwise, you can use `locals()`.

Comment: Creating variables like this is not good Python practice.  While possible, it has a foreign feel, imported from some more 'primitive' language.

Comment: You may be right about that. I just tried to answer OP's question. That's it. You know what they say: desperate times require desparate measures.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) said in comment, you should use dictionary (`dict` in Python) by setting `file_name` as key.

As per your error, when you create a numpy array, you should provide an `iterable` (ex. a `list`).

For example:

```
>>> folder = ['file1', 'file2']
>>> blabla = 0
>>> blabla1 = 1

>>> {f: np.array((blabla, blabla1)) for f in folder}
{'file1': array([0, 1]), 'file2': array([0, 1])}
```